# Problem with displacement in my code in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a simulation of galaxies that attract each other. The key aspect here is that the galaxies have different weights, and the lighter ones move towards those with greater weight and shorter distance. However, I'm encountering an issue where the numbers on the grid are not moving correctly. Can someone help me with this problem?

In my code, there are two numbers to experiment with. Specifically, I want the number 2 to move up to reach the position of the number 8. This is the full code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class galaxias_char {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        int rows = 10;
        int cols = 10;
        int depth = 10;

        char[][][] grid = new char[rows][cols][depth];

        InicializarTablero(grid);

        grid[0][2][2] = '8';
        grid[0][8][7] = '2';

        for(int gen = 1; gen <= 50; gen++){
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n--> [Generación " + gen + "]");
            imprimirTablero(grid);

            // logica de desplazamiento y demás:
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < grid[i][j].length; k++) {

                        if(calcularDistancia(grid, i, j, k) != Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                            int distanciaMásCercana = calcularDistancia(grid, i, j, k);
                            desplazamiento(grid, distanciaMásCercana, i, j, k);
                            System.out.println("-> Distancia: " + distanciaMásCercana);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // inicialización de tablero vacío con puntos.
    public static void InicializarTablero(char[][][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < grid[i][j].length; k++) {
                    grid[i][j][k] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // imprimir el tablero porque los arrays apestan:
    public static void imprimirTablero(char[][][] grid) {
        for (int capa = 0; capa < grid.length; capa++) {

            System.out.println("\n-> {Capa: " + capa + "}");

            for (int fila = 0; fila < grid[capa].length; fila++) {

                for (int columna = 0; columna < grid[capa][fila].length; columna++) {
                    System.out.print(grid[capa][fila][columna] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    // hacer la función que devuelve la distancia a la que esta un valor de su destino:
    public static int calcularDistancia(char[][][] grid, int x, int y, int z){

        int distanciaMásCercana = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < grid[i][j].length; k++) {
                    if(grid[i][j][k] != '.' && grid[x][y][z] != '.' && Character.getNumericValue(grid[i][j][k]) > Character.getNumericValue(grid[x][y][z])){

                        int distancia = Math.abs(x - i) + Math.abs(y - j) + Math.abs(z - k);

                        if(distancia < distanciaMásCercana){
                            distanciaMásCercana = distancia;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return distanciaMásCercana;
    }

    // función de desplazamiento (parte critica):
    public static void desplazamiento(char[][][] grid, int distancia, int x, int y, int z){
        int[] dx = { -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] dy = { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] dz = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0 };

        int newX = x;
        int newY = y;
        int newZ = z;

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

            int X = newX + dx[i];
            int Y = newY + dy[i];
            int Z = newZ + dz[i];

            if (X >= 0 && X < grid.length && Y >= 0 && Y < grid[0].length && Z >= 0 && Z < grid[0][0].length){

                int newDistance = Math.abs(newX - X) + Math.abs(newY - Y) + Math.abs(newZ - Z);

                if (newDistance < distancia && grid[X][Y][Z] == '.') {
                    distancia = newDistance;
                    newX = X;
                    newY = Y;
                    newZ = Z;
                }

                System.out.println("---> newDistance: " + newDistance);
            }
        }

        grid[newX][newY][newZ] = grid[x][y][z];
        grid[x][y][z] = '.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In the first instance have you tried any of debugging, adding trace statements or unit test to figure why your code is going wrong?  From my point of view, I think you should think less about arrays and more about points and vectors and create these as classes for your simulator to manipulate.

Comment: In **desplazamiento** method, shouldn't dx, dy, dz have 27 combination ? with x, y, z axis having 1, 0, -1 combination for each ? so 3×3×3 = 27